# Change method of granting permission with claims based

Tags: permissions, authentication, claims-based-auth

Our SharePoint site has claims based authentication right now and we want to change the default method of granting permissions. Whenever a new user is added all related permissions should be adjusted at same time.

For example: "j.smith" is added to the site and there are options to select which lists or libraries he can access plus the type of his permissions on those lists or libraries could be set.

Comment: some users there? had profiles then you migrate to new technology and lose last login method and change it to new method? then want to gave access them to their profile ? with new account in new method to legacy tech? how many users?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I'm going to assume that you have a proscribed set of permission that should be assigned to certain users.  First work out what your default users should have access to in terms of view/edit/manage etc. for each part of the site. Next either create a new user group or use the Members group. As a general rule you'll likely have a view permission for some libraries and an edit permission for others.

Ensure that your chosen group has the appropriate permissions for each library. Where they don't you'll want to hit the "Shared With" button in the ribbon, hit Advanced and then you can customise the permissions for the list. Stop the list from inheriting permissions. Then check the box next to the group you're working with and hit "Edit User Permission" in the next screen you can assign the permission level you want that group to have for that list. Rinse and repeat for all your groups and libraries.

If you need a permission level that is different to the OOTB permissions, commonly we see "Contribute without delete", then either edit or create a new permission level by going Site Setting > Site Permissions and hitting the "Permission Levels" button in the ribbon.

If you're using AD groups then you can just assign the AD Group to the SharePoint Group and permissions will flow down that way. Otherwise you'll need to manually assign your users into the group that corresponds to the permissions that they should have.

As a final note you can set a default group to assign users to when they join a site via the "Make Default Group" option of the settings menu when editing the membership of a group.